# How do i disable or Remove the Native Wordpress Video Player?

Tags: video-player

Any idea on how I can totally disable or entirely remove the default/Native Wordpress video player?

Comment: Note that if you do this it'll revert to the default player the browser provides, which will appear very different from browser to browser. This may also break playlists

Answer (score 8, accepted):

welcome aboard.

WordPress uses Media Elements JS for default video/audio player. You can disable this scripts with this code. Please add this code to **your theme's** `functions.php`

```php
 function deregister_media_elements(){
   wp_deregister_script('wp-mediaelement');
   wp_deregister_style('wp-mediaelement');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','deregister_media_elements');
```

PS. This code de-register mediaelements.js from all WordPress (with your current theme).

Answer (score 1):

Serkan's answer removed only some mediaelement files for me.
This removed it completely:

```php
    function deregister_media_elements(){
       wp_deregister_script('mediaelement');
       wp_deregister_style('mediaelement');
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','deregister_media_elements');
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this method, by using this piece of code you will eliminate watching online option from users. The file will be automatically downloaded as somebody enters the page.